# Query SQL from C# bad performances (much slower than VBA)

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance

I'm using a C# function to query the DB based on `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` but performances are quite bad when I try to retrieve a huge number of rows (few millions).

```
using (SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, mySqlConnection)){
    mySqlConnection.Open();
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    using (SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand)) { 
        affectedRow = mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to optimize this query for big data set?

---

Just as a comparison this piece of VBA code requires only 4-5 versus 20-22 seconds of above C#

```
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cnt.Open
Set rst = cnt.Execute(queryString)
Dim nDimArray As Variant
nDimArray = rst.GetRows
cnt.Close
```

Comment: Aren't you doing two different things here? In C# you are storing the results in memory and in VB you are just looping without doing anything to the data.

Comment: Without showing the SQL you're running not much can be said. Also, it's not surprising the VBA code runs fast: it doesn't do anything all, as shown.

Comment: The performance is different because you are doing different things... in the VBA code you **don't do anything with the data**, in the C# you do.

Comment: Ok sorry I cut too much from the VBA test code, i updated the post. Anyway it's much faster

Comment: Do you need to have all the rows in memory at one time?  If not, then use a datareader, if so, then create a class to represent one row of data and read it into a List of that class.  DataSets/DataTables are dynamic and carry some significant overhead.  You might consider even feeding the List a fairly accurate initial capacity to further improve performance.

Comment: One thing you haven't show is how you are timing the two methods.  Have you accounted for C# JIT time?  Other factors?

Comment: @Naigel I'm confused as to how the code you had before your edits and the code you now have both ran in 4-5 seconds.  I don't believe it.  I suggest you actually write code that implements your test, and then run actual benchmarks using that same code.

Comment: @RobertMcKee thank you for the suggestion, I thought `DataTables` were somehow optimized for these situations and always perform better than `List`. Maybe a `SELECT count(*)` to find exact row number prior to instantiate the `List` can perform even better?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I just got `Date` before and after the query. It's not the best option but difference is high, so I don't care to get exact timing.
@RobertMcKee in the first version I just cut out too much code, the test code is actually the one above plus variable initializations and dates

Comment: The only thing that DataTables does really well is mass update/inserts via batching, and actually that is a function of the dataadapter.  As for doing a COUNT(*) first, you probably won't gain enough performance to make that worthwhile.  Just use an approximate number, in your case, 1 million or 2 million should suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use DataSet.  Use a SqlReader which is similar to what you were doing in VBA.

```
using (var mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, mySqlConnection))
{
    mySqlConnection.Open();
    var reader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You should be able to do this as well, which will clean up after yourself just in case you have exceptions thrown during the read:

```
using (var mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, mySqlConnection))
    {
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        using (var reader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SqlReader is generally the recommended method if your logic can process the retrieved records individually, meaning, you don't have to have all data in memory. If you need to have all millions of rows in memory to calculate statistics or so, you might not get around an approach like the DataSet.

Comment: Why aren't you adding `using` to the SqlDataReader also?

Comment: Updated answer with using `using` for the SqlDataReader, but the code from Microsoft doesn't use it either.

Comment: Time down using this method, nearly 70% less if I populate a list of objects with each row data, and by 80% if I create a specific class instead of using objects. Well now performances are much better, thank you!